# How do I shut down wsgiserver with flask ontop

Tags: python, flask

I have flask running ontop of wsgiserver. It is started with the following..

```
d = wsgiserver.WSGIPathInfoDispatcher({'/': app}) 
server = wsgiserver.CherryPyWSGIServer(('0.0.0.0', 7000), d)

if __name__ == '__main__': 

    try: 
        server.start() 

    except KeyboardInterrupt: 
        server.stop()
```

How do I stop it? So..

```
@app.route('/stop')
@requires_auth
def stop():
    CODE TO STOP HERE
```

I have searched google high and low and nothing I've found has worked. Please could someone assist. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
def run():
    d = wsgiserver.WSGIPathInfoDispatcher({'/': app}) 
    server = wsgiserver.CherryPyWSGIServer(('0.0.0.0', 7000), d)

    @app.route('/stop')
    @requires_auth
    def stop():
        server.stop()

    try:
        server.start()

    except KeyboardInterrupt: 
        server.stop()

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    run()
```